# Fastest polling loop - how can I trim 1 CPU cycle?

Tags: assembly, cortex-m, micro-optimization

In a realtime application¹ on an ARM Cortex M3 (similar to STM32F101), I need to poll a bit of an internal peripheral's register until it's zero, in as tight a loop as possible. I use bit banding to access the appropriate bit. The (working) C code is

```
while (*(volatile uint32_t*)kMyBit != 0);
```

That code is copied in on-chip executable RAM. After some manual optimization² the polling loop is down to the following, that I timed³ to 6 cycles:

```
0x00600200 681A      LDR      r2,[r3,#0x00]
0x00600202 2A00      CMP      r2,#0x00
0x00600204 D1FC      BNE      0x00600200
```

**How can the polling uncertainty be lowered?** A 5-cycle loop would fit my goal: sample that same bit as close as possible to 15.5 cycles after it went to zero.

My spec calls for reliably detecting a low pulse at least 6.5 CPU clock cycles; reliably classifying it as short if it lasts less than 12.5 cycles; and reliably classifying it as long if its lasts more than 18.5 cycles. The pulses have no defined phase relationship with the CPU clock, which is my only accurate timing reference. That requires an at-most 5-clock polling loop. Actually I'm emulating code that ran on a decades-old 8-bit CPU that could poll with a 5-clock cycle, and what that did has become the spec.

---

I tried to offset the code alignment by inserting NOP before the loop, in the many variants I tried, but never observed a change.

I tried to invert the CMP and LDR, but still get 6 cycles:

```
0x00600200 681A      LDR      r2,[r3,#0x00]
; we loop here
0x00600202 2A00      CMP      r2,#0x00
0x00600204 681A      LDR      r2,[r3,#0x00]
0x00600206 D1FC      BNE      0x00600202
```

This one is 8 cycles

```
0x00600200 681A      LDR      r2,[r3,#0x00]
0x00600202 681A      LDR      r2,[r3,#0x00]
0x00600204 2A00      CMP      r2,#0x00
0x00600206 D1FB      BNE      0x00600200
```

But this one is 9 cycles:

```
0x00600200 681A      LDR      r2,[r3,#0x00]
0x00600202 2A00      CMP      r2,#0x00
0x00600204 681A      LDR      r2,[r3,#0x00]
0x00600206 D1FB      BNE      0x00600200
```

---

¹ Measuring how much time the bit is low, in a context where no interrupt occurs.

² The initial compiler-generated code used r12 as the destination register, and that added 4 code bytes to the loop, costing 1 cycle.

³ The numbers given are obtained with a supposedly cycle-accurate real-time [STIce emulator](https://web.archive.org/web/20190420015049/http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/f2/9c/d5/ad/3e/bf/4a/08/CD00154442.pdf/files/CD00154442.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00154442.pdf) and its *emulator trigger* feature on read at the register's address. Previously I tried the "States" counter with a breakpoint in the loop, but the result depends on the breakpoint's location. Single-step is even worse: it always give 4 cycles for LDR, when that's at least sometime down to 3.

Comment: alignment can matter, the gpio clock domain might dominate the performance as well as the flash wait states, it will be 3+ clocks but could be 6+ or even more depending. I would expect bit banding not to be a performance hit for reads, but you could test the bit rather than compare for zero and see.  bottom line you have to just try it...

Comment: there isnt a way to interrupt?  I understand that the latency on the interrupt would be much slower than polling but you are isolating the cpu on this one thing for this duration

Comment: @old_timer: I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) no contention between RAM and this register. There indeed is not way to generate an interrupt on this particular bit, at least as in the register where I read it. As you noted, interrupt latency would be a barely tolerable issue.

Comment: this is not a register in ram if it is in a peripheral it is a peripheral register, different data path from the processor to the register and back.  now saying ram though you could run this code in ram and overcome the flash latency.  being ST it has a cache in front of the flash that should eliminate the latency, but in general with MCUS the flash is at or slower than the processor clock, you just have to experiment here though, which is true in general for benchmarking.

Comment: @old_timer: Indeed the register is not RAM, and that's part of why I hope no contention. I already run the code from on-chip executable zero-wait-state RAM (as the question states) precisely to overcome Flash latency, which has already bitten me (it seems to makes alignment critical when branching, in a way that I quit predicting down to the last cycle). I'l trying the code, but one of my problems is measuring my loop time. I try to generate a pulse on register access using a hardware trigger out built in the supposedly cycle-accurate emulator, but that's not working yet.

Comment: Doesn't Thumb mode have a cbnz instruction to compare-and-branch on another register being zero?  Did you compile with `gcc -Os -mcpu=cortex-m3`?

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I'm not using gcc, but ArmCC 5 (ARM's previous generation compiler before going LLVM). Optimization is for time and to the max, and the options for the CPU are supposed to be automagically set by the IDE, but I'll check that. Yes there is CBZ/CBNZ, but as I read the [doc](https://static.docs.arm.com/dui0552/a/DUI0552A_cortex_m3_dgug.pdf#page=109) it can not branch backward.

Comment: depends on which bus they wired things up toi wouls assume separate on an m3

Comment: Oh, you're right, http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289867296.htm also confirms that Thumb CBZ/CBNZ can only jump forwards, not backwards.  That explains why your compiler can't use them.  Fun fact: AArch64 CBZ/CBNZ *can* jump forward or backwards (which makes sense; AArch64 instructions are all 32 bits wide so there's plenty of space for a signed displacement.)  I guess most loops have a counter and you can usually branch on how `subs` sets flags so Thumb decided to give it more forward range instead of just a 2's complement displacement.

Comment: Ok, so you (or the compiler) could unroll with `ldr`/`cbz reg, end_of_loop` for the inner ones, and still a `cmp`/`bnz` at the bottom.  But that would give you a non-uniform polling interval e.g. 1 in every 8 polls, in case that matters.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't misinterpreted the spec? Maybe the spec if referring to "device specific cycles that are not CPU cycles" (e.g. a timer or UART with its own clock source that has much slower cycles), and maybe "as short as 13 device specific cycles" could be "as short as 13000 CPU specific cycles".

Comment: @Brendan: Yes I'm sure. First, I can see the pulses on a scope and what they do on my code. And I'm emulating code that ran on an earlier 8-bit CPU that could poll with a 5-clock cycle; doing at least as good as this CPU has become the spec.

Comment: How fast was your 8-bit CPU and how fast is you current ARM CPU?

Comment: @Ross Ridge: while doing that stunt, my CPUs run at an externally-supplied clock of 1 to 5 MHz (varies depending on the stuff I'm plugged in, and by a factor of 2 depending on if it's preparing to send a pulse or not). On the 8-bit CPU, that was the only clocking option. On the ARM, I have the software-selectable option to run at about 30MHz from an internal clock (not stable). I have thought of polling at 30MHz internal clock then switching to external to measure the pulse, but I have no spec on how much time the switch takes, and that would increase idle power drastically.

Comment: So your pulse is now 6 times faster?

Comment: @Ross Ridge: no. My external clock cycle and pulse duration have not changed: tc = 200 to 1000ns, tpshort=6.5*tc to 12.5*tc, tplong>18.5*tc. My CPU run from that external clock, that's unchanged too. The main new thing compared to 8 bit legacy is that I use an ARM, which tends to use more cycles to poll a bit change. I mentioned the possibility to run the ARM at 30 MHz because you asked, but I don't plan to use it because power consumption, and lack of known relation with external clock cycle, which is the unit defining the pulse to measure. It's best to forget that 30MHz figure IMHO.

Comment: @fgrieu: There's something very wrong with your numbers. To detect a 200 ns pulse reliably (to avoid sampling just before rising edge then just after falling edge and concluding "no pulse occurred") you must exceed a rate of 5 million samples per second (or, with "5 CPU cycles" per sample, you must use a 25 MHz or faster CPU); and that is just to detect that a pulse occurred without caring how long the pulse is. To measure pulse length with 50 ns precision (e.g. to be able to say "pulse was between 250 ns and 300 ns long"), with "5 CPU cycles" per sample, you'd need a 100 MHz or faster CPU.

Comment: @brendan: to clarify: tc istands for the CLOCK cycle time, sorry that was not clear enough. A short pulse is a minimum of 6.5 times that, and a maximum of 12.5 times that. A long pulse is at least 18.5 times that. From the standpoint of the CPU, 6.5, 12.5 and 18.5 are the relevant limits, irrelevant of the clock speed. I wish I had stated that right when Ross Ridge asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it's not necessarily the loop cycles that need to be reduced, but the number of cycles between consequent samples (i.e. LDR instructions). But there can be more than one LDR per iteration. You can try something like this:

```
    ldrb    r1, [r0]

loop:
    cbz     r1, out
    ldrb    r2, [r0]
    cbz     r2, out
    ldrb    r1, [r0]
    b       loop

out:
```

The spacing between the two LDRB instructions varies so the samples aren't uniformly spaced.

This may delay exit from the loop slightly, but from the problem description I can't say if it's important or not.

I happen to have access to cycle-accurate M7 model, and when the process stabilises your original loop runs on M7 in 3 cycles per iteration (meaning LDR every 3 cycles), while the proposed loop above runs in 4 cycles, but now there are two LDRs in there (so LDR every 2 cycles). Sampling rate is definitely improved.

To give credit, unrolling with CBZ as a break was proposed by [@Peter Cordes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790885/fastest-polling-loop-how-can-i-trim-1-cpu-cycle#comment105728458_59790885).

Admittedly M3 will be slower but it's still worth a shot, if it's the sampling rate you're after.

Also you can check if LDRB instead of LDR (as in the code above) changes anything, although I don't expect it to.

UPD: I have another 2-LDR loop version which on M7 completes in 3 cycles which you can try out of interest (also CBZ breaks allow for easy balancing of the paths after the loop):

```
    ldr     r1, [r0]

loop:
    ldr     r2, [r0]
    cbz     r1, out_slow
    cbz     r2, out_fast
    ldr     r1, [r0]
    b       loop

out_fast:
    /* NOPs as required */

out_slow:
```

Comment: Good news: that runs at 10 cycle/loop with 2 samplings, thus the average sample rate is OK. Serious problem: the delay between samples is 4 cycles from the one going to `r2` to the one going to `r1`, but **6 cycles** from the one going to `r1` to the one going to `r2` (due to the `b  loop` in between), when I want (at most) 5 cycles between samplings. An easily fixed problem is that we reach `out` after a larger delay following sample if the exit is because `r1` is zero than when it is because `r2` is zero. In other news, `ldrb` from a bit-banding address caused issues, changed to `ldr`.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Didn't want to go into equalising the samples before confirming that the basic idea worked for you. Also it's hard to predict how my M7 runs translate into M3. I gave you that loop version because it produced uniform sample rate on M7 (LDR every 2 cycles). But I also had another version which actually went faster on M7 (3 cycles per loop and still 2 LDRs), you can try it out of interest. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I confirm that your second polling loop runs in 10 cycles with two equally-spaced samples on my Cortex-M3 emu. It trounces my answer (now removed) on simplicity, and allows to test shorter pulses. 2 `nop` before `loop:` and 4 `nop` after `out_fast:` makes it such that a `ldr` after `out_slow:` samples 10 cycles after the sample that was first seen at zero, whichever of the three that was. My spec (as worded in the question) requires 13, and that's trivial to adjust. Problem 100% solved! Many thanks, as well as to Peter Cordes for his comment, and B Degan for the first bounty.

Comment: @fgrieu: oh yeah, that is a clever trick in the latest update.  `out_fast` could maybe be more compact than 5 `nop`s, perhaps just doing another `ldr`, or maybe doing a `b` to the next instruction, if that takes more cycles than a NOP on your CPU without polluting branch prediction (if any).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this but i am suspicious that it will give same 6 cycles

```
0x00600200 581a      LDR      r2,[r3,r0]; initialize r0 to 0x0
0x00600202 4282      CMP      r2,r0
0x00600204 D1FC      BNE      0x00600200
```